# Training Spacy custom entities from excel sheet

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm new to the NLP and have come across one problem while training spacy format data.

```
TRAIN_DATA = [
    ("Who is Shaka Khan?", {"entities": [(7, 17, "PERSON")]}),
    ("I like London and Berlin.", {"entities": [(7, 13, "LOC"), (18, 24, "LOC")]}),
]
```

Data is getting trained in the above format but since I have vast amount of data in TRAIN_DATA, so I was thinking is it possible to store the TRAIN_DATA in excel sheet and train them as it is getting trained above.

Please spare some time to help me out in this problem.

Comment: You can keep the data in an excel sheet if you convert it. Are you have trouble converting it? It's not clear what your problem is.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70170284/if-there-are-any-other-approaches-to-maintain-train-data-in-a-separate-file-inst

Comment: @polm23 Thanks for the response, Yeah I'm having trouble in converting it as how my excel sheet will look like and how the data will get trained without (start, end) points. Kindly help me out.

Comment: So you don't have an Excel sheet, you want to make one and want help designing it? Well, you can't use data that doesn't have (start, end) points, for one thing. For another it's hard to store this in Excel because there's no guarantee there's one entity per line. I guess you need to make a join table but I don't know how to use that in Excel. Excel seems like a pretty bad way to store the data to me, if you don't want it in code you can use a bare JSON file.

Comment: @polm23 thanks, I'll do it with json file, since I've vast amount of data in TRAIN_DATA, is there any shorcut to convert above TRAIN_DATA into json file. I can do it manually but if there's any tool that will be great.